# Airflow PostgresToGCSOperator - Exporting the Timestamp column in EPOCH format

Tags: python, airflow

Im using PostgresToGCSOperator [[v1.10](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/contrib/operators/postgres_to_gcs_operator.py) and [v2.0](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/postgres_to_gcs.py)] to export the data. I know there is a mapping in that operator. I have changed that and made as a custom operator. If Postgres has timestamp then in BQ use DATETIME for timestampz use TIMESTAMP.

```
       1114: 'DATETIME',
        1184: 'TIMESTAMP',
        1082: 'DATE',
        1083: 'TIME',
        1005: 'INTEGER',
        1007: 'INTEGER',
        1016: 'INTEGER',
        20: 'INTEGER',
        21: 'INTEGER',
        23: 'INTEGER',
        16: 'BOOLEAN',
        700: 'FLOAT',
        701: 'FLOAT',
        1700: 'FLOAT'
```

But while exporting, this data in CSV format, it won't be considering this and export the value in EPOCH format. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One more best option: Customized Airflow Postgres to GCS operator. So you can CSV or JSON and no restrictions.

Replace this on the original operator:

```py
type_map = {
        1114: 'DATETIME',
        1184: 'TIMESTAMP',
        1082: 'DATE',
        1083: 'TIME',
        1005: 'INTEGER',
        1007: 'INTEGER',
        1016: 'INTEGER',
        20: 'INTEGER',
        21: 'INTEGER',
        23: 'INTEGER',
        16: 'BOOLEAN',
        700: 'FLOAT',
        701: 'FLOAT',
        1700: 'FLOAT',
    }
```

And the Conversion:

```py
        if isinstance(value, (datetime.datetime, datetime.date)):
            return str(value)
        if isinstance(value, datetime.time):
            return str(value)
        if isinstance(value, Decimal):
            return float(value)
        return value
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a tricky workaround for this. We can convert the output as JSON from the postgres itself using `row_to_json` function. Then export it to GCS.

But there are some glitches.

1. The `schema file` will have only one column. So you have to deal with it.
2. It has `row_to_json` as a header.
3. While loading use source format as `NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON`, but during the export use `CSV` with delimiter as `|` else it'll add unnessesary quotes.
4. Crate a `schema file manually` and use it.
5. Use `max bad records as 1` since the header name will not be parsed.
6. While loading use `autodetect=False`

#### Sample:

```
sql='SELECT row_to_json(t) FROM (SELECT * FROM mytbl) t'
```

#### Output:

```
row_to_json
{'id': 1, 'c1': '2020-10-16', 'c2': '10:20:30', 'c3': '2020-10-16T10:20:30', 'c4': '2020-10-16T04:50:30+00:00'}
```